Point-in-Time-Recovery of Postgres at an arbitrary time for audit purposes
TL;DR
Would you recommend using CDC or pg_wal-based recovery to reproduce the state of the database in an arbitrary time, or stick with joining SCD2 tables (with start end end date for every record) and query all data before given date?
We are developing a new microservice to support our application. For audit purposes our calculations need to be reproducible, so the current plan is to use SCD2 with every record having a start_date and an end_date. This way the state of the database at a given time can be reproduced if calculation from the past needs to be reproduced (if ever requested). Joining and maintaining versioned SCD2 tables seem to be cumbersome, but that is the current plan.
Would making the database store only the current state, i.e. updates would actually update a record, and not just mark it obsolete and insert a new state; and archiving the replica level WAL files with sufficiently good granularity, and rebuilding the state on-demand work?
Or keeping an audit table and rebuild from that?
The scale/magnitude is around a 100k records per year.
Any thoughts welcome.
P.S. we don't have a DBA on the team.

"archiving the replica level WAL files with sufficiently good granularity"  replay can be stopped within a WAL file (using recovery_target_time) to microsecond granularity, so the granularity of the archiving doesn't matter.

Your question seems to suggest that these audits don't happen very often, so I would suggest that you keep base backups and a WAL archive around, and when you need the state of the database at a certain time, you restore a backup on some different system and recover to the desired point in time.
That is a fairly complicated way to access old data, but you don't have to lug any superfluous data around in the production database, and it puts no extra strain on the server, since you need backups anyway.
